# How to make the gitlab-ci found my deploy file?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a script to make deploy but the gitlab ci not found it, my yml:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls
    - cd scripts
    - pwd
    - ls
    - chmod +x ./deploy.sh
    - ./deploy.sh
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - master
```

The result of this in the terminal:

```
$ ls
index.js
package-lock.json
package.json
scripts
$ cd scripts
$ pwd
/builds/project-0/scripts
$ ls
deploy.sh
$ chmod +x ./deploy.sh
$ ./deploy.sh
/bin/sh: eval: line 47: ./deploy.sh: not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
FATAL: exit code 127
```

As you can see, the file is there with permission but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that before and it's most likely that the base image that is running the job is using `/bin/sh` and your script is requesting for a shell that the base image doesn't contain.

Does your `deploy.sh` script have the following shebang `#!/bin/bash` (or any other shell that is not `sh`)?

To solve your issue either change your base image with one that contains the shell you are looking for or change `deploy.sh` to use `#!/bin/sh` if your script can run in a POSIX shell.

Comment: Yes, I already read this solution in others sites but still the same problem.... as bin/bash or bin/sh :(

Comment: I just assumed you were running a docker executor but what kind of executor are you using for gitlab-ci? 

Is it possible to see the content of the `deploy.sh` script? Alternatively could you replace the deploy script by running another simple script that uses a posix shell and do something simple like: `echo "Hello world"`?

Answer (score 0):

I fix using the ubuntu image and call bash

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: ubuntu
  script:
    - chmod +x ./scripts/deploy.sh
    - bash ./scripts/deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
```